# Number of possible components

Tags: vector-analysis

In Principal Components Analysis, how many components are possible? If we have $n$ observation and $p$ variables, is it possible to have $n$ components?

Answer (score 0):

You may have up to $p$ components (this is the typical case), since PCA is done by taking the $n \times p$ matrix $X$ and computing the eigenvalues of $X^TX$.

Comment: I thought it was done by computing the eigenvalues of either the covariance matrix or the correlation matrix? $X^{T}X$ is the covariance matrix?

Comment: From the wikipedia article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis):

Depending on the field of application, it is also named the ... singular value decomposition (SVD) of X (Golub and Van Loan, 1983), eigenvalue decomposition (EVD) of $X^TX$ in linear algebra,...